# How to avoid calling `updateFunc` on sync?

Tags: go, controller, kubernetes

From what I understand (and experience) - kubernetes informers calls `updateFunc` each "sync" event of its cache - From what I gather it is due to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/117d288bbeebfecd84ac5dde6a31dc16ee2ae55d/tools/cache/controller.go#L305) annoying peace of code.

An example informer definition:

```
informer:= NewInformer(
&cache.ListWatch{
ListFunc: func(options api.ListOptions) (runtime.Object, error) {
  return kubeClient.Batch().Jobs(api.NamespaceAll).List(options)
},
WatchFunc: func(options api.ListOptions) (watch.Interface, error) {
  return kubeClient.Batch().Jobs(api.NamespaceAll).Watch(options)
},....)

...

informer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
    AddFunc: func(obj interface{}){},
    // Make this function be called *only* on update. 
    UpdateFunc: func(old, current interface{}){},
    DeleteFunc: func(current interface{}){},
})
```

But for my use case - calling `updateFunc` should really happen only when that resource is updated (e.g. I am doing some intense computation on each update or going to I/O).

I was wandering is there a way to call `updateFunc` only on update?

Comment: Possible idea I had in mind: Getting the most "current" `resourceVersion` in the `Store` and then comparing it to the most current `resourceVersion` synced (using the `informer.LastSyncedResourceVersion` field) to check if the cache is ahead of the sync which would indicate a "real" update has occurred but I am not sure what is the `resourceVersion` contract - And have been told not to trust it will incrument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer [in this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/529):

> If resourceVersion differs between old and new, an actual update event was observed.